# Branch Cut for $\ln(1 - z^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

"Given that $g(z) = \ln(1-z^2)$, defined on $\mathbb{C}\backslash \left(-\infty, 1\right]$, i.e. the branch cut is from $-\infty$ to $1$ along the real axis. Find $g(-i)$ given $g(i) = \ln(2)$"

I tried drawing it out but I'm having trouble making sense of this. I understand how $(-\infty, 0]$ works as a branch cut for $\ln(z)$. If  $\ln(z) = a + bi$ we restrict $-\pi<b < \pi $ so there is a single value for $\ln(z)$. This means every time $z$ passes through $(-\infty, 0]$ there is a discontinuous jump in the value of $\ln(z)$.

However I've not been successful for explaining how $-\infty$ to $1$ works for  $g(z) = \ln(1-z^2)$.

It seems like if $\left| z\right|^2 > 1$, then making the argument of z go around a circle causes the argument of $1 - z^2$ to go around a circle *twice*.

Comment: Choose the branch cut for $\log(z)$ as all the points $z\geq 0 $ So  we have $0 \leq \text{Arg}(z) < 2 \pi $ .Similarly  we have $1-z^2 \geq  0$ so we have $z^2\leq 1$ So the branch cut is along the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Zaid Alyafeai, I'm not sure what is meant by $ z \geq 0 $ since there is not total ordering for the complex numbers. I also don't really follow your comment very well. This stuff is fairly new to me.

Comment: The Maple 17 code                                              $$                                                    expression:= log(-z^2+1):FunctionAdvisor(branch \_cuts, expression, plot = '2D');                                                       $$   produces                                                                                                                  $$                                                                          [ \log \left( -z^2+1 \right) ,1<z , z<-1],                                 $$ where $z <-1$ means $z$ is a real number satisfying the inequality

Comment: I ignored that because we are working on the Real line since you are interested in the branch cut along the real axis . The branch cut of $\log(z)$ can be chosen along the real axis and since $z=0$ is a branch point it has to be contained in any branch cut . so we can choose the branch cut to be $z\leq 0$ or $z \geq 0$ where for $z\leq 0$ defines the principle logarithm with $-\pi \leq \text{Arg(z)} <\pi$ Now assume for arbitrary function $f(z)$ we can find the branch cut of principle logarithm as follows we choose $f(z)\leq 0$ and this implies $-\pi \leq \text{Arg}f(z) <\pi$

$$

Comment: Take a path from $i$ to $-i$ in the domain. Say a straight line segment from $i$ to $2$, then the line segment from $2$ to $-i$. Trace the mapped path under the map $z \mapsto 1 - z^2$. You get a closed path from $2$ to $2$. How many times (orientation counts) does that path wind around zero? Then you will find $g(-i) = \log 2 + 2\pi i\cdot N$ where $N$ is the winding number.

Comment: @DanielFischer will you make your comment an answer so it will be answered?